# How to make a bash script to run fakeroot and exit from fakeroot?

Tags: linux, bash

I have following bash script, I want to enter to fakeroot environment, then run other commands, then exit, which I can run my laptop ubuntu terminal.

```
$ cat test_root.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -u
set -e
fakeroot
echo "my $UID"
exit
```

But that script won't work, appreciate your clues to fix it.

```
$ ./test_root.sh
root\#
root\# exit
exit
my 1000
```

Thank you.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

From [man fakeroot](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=man+fakeroot) it's `fakeroot -- command`

```
$ fakeroot sh -c 'echo "my $UID"'
my 0
```